# How to get related posts and wp comments under tabs

Tags: tabs, comments-template

I am a novice and want to show two tabs under every wordpress post. Under the first tab there would be related posts and under the second tab there would be wp comments. So The default comment area should be disabled.
I have also managed to create tabs using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabby-responsive-tabs/ and adding the following code to my child theme's functions.php.

```
  function add_post_content($content) {
  if(!is_feed() && !is_home()) { 

   $above = '<p></p>';
   $below = '[tabby title="First Tab"]

      code needed to show related posts here...

          [tabby title="Second Tab"]

      <?php comments_template(); ?>

          [tabbyending]';

   $content = "$above $content $below";
  }
 return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

But is it the correct way? And of course, the comments are not showing by this code. So please provide a working code for the related posts (no thumbnail) and the comments to show up in the respective tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use do_shortcode() for the shortcode to actually work inside PHP

```
 function add_post_content($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_home()) { 

    $above = '<p></p>';
    $content_of_first_tab = 'A list of related posts ';


    $args= array(
        'number'  => '5',
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(), // use post_id, not post_ID.
         );
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    $output = '';
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) :
        $output .= $comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content. '<br />';
    endforeach;
    $content_of_second_tab = $output ;
    $below = do_shortcode( '[tabby title="First Tab"]' . $content_of_first_tab . '[tabby title="Second Tab"]'. $content_of_second_tab. '[tabbyending]'  );

    $content = $above.''.$content .''.$below;
    }
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_post_content');
```

This question is specific to a plugin and should be posted in the appropriate [support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/tabby-responsive-tabs)

Do **not** copy and paste code unless you know what you're doing.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it's a question about my custom development, not the plugin.

Comment: Does the code example I provided work for you?

Comment: Yes it works, but not the way I wanted it. It's showing a list of comments. But I want to show the whole comments template with all the comments, the reply and edit links and the comment submission form.

Comment: I've pointed you in the right direction, I can't post the whole source code, this kind of task requires some digging into your theme files, I understand how you want it but it's not possible to make it happen without actually viewing your theme files. You should first learn on how WordPress comments template works and then you can implement it in the example code I provided.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct and accept it and then ask another question on comments template file in WordPress.

Comment: Yes, I think I can do that after some more investigations. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll be happy to answer your next question about comment template file, after you accept this one. And ask another question specific to it.